# Java Swing - How do I make it so that closing a Dialog box doesn't close the entire program?

Tags: java, swing

For some course work I have to make a browser using swing and implement multiple features, such as a bookmark feature. What I am trying to do here is have a class for a new window that displays a drop down menu of my stored bookmarks.

I used a dialog box here because I didn't want the window to have a minimize button but however, when you close the dialog box now the entire program closes (the actual browser JFrame and everything else in the program).

I have set the setDefaultCloseOperation of the Dlg box to DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE but it does not seem to work, I also tried to simply HIDE the box.

Here is my code, wondering if I did something wrong or its just down to how Dialog boxes work. Cheers

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.event.ItemEvent;
import java.awt.event.ItemListener;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JComboBox;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class SeeBookmarks extends JFrame {

    private JComboBox<String> seeBookmarks = new JComboBox<String>();       //Drop down box for the bookmarks

    public SeeBookmarks(BrowserPane screen, JButton seeBookmarksBtn) throws IOException {
        Dlg bookmarksFrame = new Dlg(new JFrame(), "Bookmarks");        //Dialog box (Replacement JFrame)

        try {
            Scanner bookmarks = new Scanner(new FileReader("bookmarks.txt"));       //Read the bookmarks file
            while (bookmarks.hasNextLine()) {                                       //While the file has another bookmark line
                seeBookmarks.addItem(bookmarks.nextLine());                         //    add it to the drop down box
            }
            bookmarks.close();          //Close file reader
        } catch (FileNotFoundException fnfe) {      //In case file does not exist
            FileWriter bookmarks = new FileWriter("bookmarks.txt");         //Create an empty bookmarks file
            bookmarks.close();          //Close file writer
        }

        seeBookmarks.addItemListener(new ItemListener() {           //Listener for the bookmarks drop down box
            public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent item) {
                if (item.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {                  //If an item is selected
                    screen.search(seeBookmarks.getSelectedItem().toString(), true); //    Search selected item, add to history
                    bookmarksFrame.dispose();                                       //    Close Dialog box
                    seeBookmarksBtn.setEnabled(true);                               //    Re-enable seeBookmarksBtn
                }
            }
        });

        bookmarksFrame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());               //Set Dialog box to Border layout
        bookmarksFrame.add(seeBookmarks, BorderLayout.CENTER);      //Display drop down box in center for dialog box

        bookmarksFrame.pack();          
        bookmarksFrame.setSize(300, 70);
        bookmarksFrame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        bookmarksFrame.setVisible(true);
        bookmarksFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(Dlg.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);      //Meant to dispose the Dialog box
        bookmarksFrame.setResizable(false);
        bookmarksFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(true);
    }

}
```

Comment: If you need more help (and in all future questions), post a proper [[mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Use [DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/WindowConstants.html#DO_NOTHING_ON_CLOSE).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I used a dialog box here

It is correct to use a dialog. In general, An application should only every have a single JFrame to control the application and then you use dialogs for child windows.

Closing a JDialog will not close the application unless there are no other active frames in the application. Note the dialog doesn't even have an "EXIT" option for setting the default close operation. So the problem is in the context of how your code is executed.

The code you posted doesn't really help:

1. we don't know what the `Dlg` class is. If you want use a JDialog, then just create a JDialog.
2. there is no need for your class to extend JFrame.
3. We don't know how this dialog code is actually invoked. Maybe you have code in the other class that causes the application to close?
4. pack() and setVisible() should be the last two statements to execute after all the component have been added to the dialog and all the dialog properties have been set. For example setting the dialog to be not resizable will change the size of the border and therefore the size of the dialog.

Comment: Changing it from Dlg to JDialog fixed it thank you, I used Dlg because its what I saw in another post about removing the resizable. Thank you for the other advice as well.